# Why can't I append using "cat >>" in bash

Tags: bash

This is probably an extremely basic question, but why can't i append any text when using this script:

```
#! /bin/bash
cat >> text_file.txt
```

I've tried to remove the space between the shebang, and the output remains the same, wherein if I enter any new text, it doesn't append or overwrite. However, If I remove one ">", the file text_file.txt gets overwritten. For example:

```
#! /bin/bash
cat > text_file.txt
```

The above actually overwrites the file text_file.txt, but adding another ">" fails to perform the append operation.

Comment: Yes you can - prove me wrong (I assume `#! /bin/bash` is a wrongly copied script or else that's the problem. Drop the space).

Comment: @Ted The space is perfectly valid. See [Is space allowed between #! and /bin/bash in shebang? (U&L)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276751/117037)

Comment: @TedLyngmo I tried that, but it still didn't work

Comment: @Newbie Please be explicit and put it in the question. How does "does not work" manifest itself?

Comment: the `cat` expect input from `stdin` so an educated guess is that your script is waiting for an input, which seems to just hang?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Okay, so here's what I mean. When I drop the space, the output still turns out to be the same. It doesn't overwrite, nor does it append any new text when performing the script.

Comment: @Newbie Click [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66617229/edit) and put the clarification in the question so that everyone sees it. Regarding: "_the output still turns out to be the same_" - Which is... what exactly?

Comment: @Newbie Your updated question made this into a much more intriguing question. +1 from me.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm learning bash for the first time to be honest, and so I wasn't sure if it was a valid issue in the first place to be honest haha.

Comment: @Newbie That's perfectly ok. I've used `bash` (or `sh` rather) for some 35 years ... and I'm intrigued by your question so for me personally, it's a perfectly valid question.

Comment: We normally use cat with a pipe structure like for example ls /etc| cat >> file.txt or if you use cat >> txt, it takes input from std input in this case it is keyboard, so you better check your standard input for the cat command

Comment: Redirection happens before anything else. In that code so `>` truncate and `>>` appends and since there is no input given then the redirection is the only thing happening in that script.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Please describe how you type in the text and how you exit `cat`. I have a feeling you type a sincle line and then press ctrl+c throwing away all puffered text that way. Try hitting enter and then ctrl-D.

Comment: Yup, got it... thank you @Socowi. That was where I was going wrong after all. My bad :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you exit `cat` using <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. This *kills* `cat` immediately so that all puffered text is lost.

The correct way to exit `cat` gracefully is hitting <kbd>enter</kbd> and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>. That way all your entered text should be appenend to the file.

Comment: I wonder which implementations of `cat` buffer anything. The GNU coreutils and Busybox ones don't appear to do that (I tried). Anyway, why would this come up only when appending and not when truncating? Shouldn't the truncating case similarly just lead to a zero-length output file?

Comment: @ilkkachu I don't think it is `cat` that does the buffering but rather `bash`'s built in readline. Inside each line you can use backspace to delete stuff -- that wouldn't be possible if every keystroke was sent to `cat` immediately. Once you press enter, the whole line is sent to `cat` which (in my case) immediately writes that line to the file. ++ At least for me there is no difference in buffering between `>` and `>>`.  But with `>` the file is immediately overwritten, even if the buffer is lost.

Comment: @Socowi, there is no Bash or Bash's readline involved when `cat` is running. Bash just reads the command `cat >> text_file.txt`, sets up the redirection and launches `cat`. It never touches the data after that. What does the line buffering, is the terminal interface, which only gives the data to `cat` when a full line has been entered. So, yes, if you suspect they hit ^C before hitting enter, then indeed that line would not reach `cat`. But the terminal doesn't buffer more than one line, unlike the stdio buffering would, if `cat` used it. Also, shouldn't that still be the same with `>`?

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this (using zsh on osx - should work on bash, too):

```
aether@voyage ~ % cat >> test.txt <<eof 
heredoc> Hi, there!
heredoc> eof
aether@voyage ~ % cat test.txt
Hi, there!
aether@voyage ~ %
```